# How does this function traverse the token through slicing, Can you please explain how it selects the elements in the list?

Tags: pytorch

The code I'm referring to:

`predicted_index = torch.argmax(predictions[0, -1, :]).item()`

Answer (score 0):

This is a `tensor` not a `list`, major difference being:

- `tensor` has one specified `dtype` (usually `float32` in PyTorch)
- faster to run operations on

Your predictions are `3D` tensor of which you are taking:

- `0`th row
- last column (`-1` index)
- all of the elements from third dimension (`:`)

Essentially your are left with a vector after the slicing.

`torch.argmax` returns **the index** under which the largest element resides, for example:

```
torch.argmax(torch.tensor([-1, 0, 1.5, 1, 0])) # would return 2'
```

Code of `argmax` is implemented in `C++` and keeps the index of largest value found until now and returns the one found at the end (`O(n)` complexity).

`.item()` changes `tensor` to it's Python counterpart (usually `float` from any floating point, `int` from integer family type etc.).

Comment: Thank you so much! also for the torch.argmax() explainer, Could you please guide me to something that has this kind of in depth explanation of methods and classes in pytorch (also regarding fast.ai, docs are not so comprehensible for beginners)

Comment: @RadJre there are a lot of tutorials, but StackOverflow is not a place for seeking books & resources recomendations. If the answer solved your question please mark it with a green tick, thank you.